# Expressing vague rates

Tags: prepositions

Normally, "po" is used to express frequency or rates. For example, "Mi manĝas po unu durianon ĉiutage" (or "Mi manĝas ĉiutage po unu durianon"). But then what if the "rate" is not very specific? For example, "I have duplicates for each situation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think

> I have duplicates for each situation.

can be seen as any "rate" or "frequency" at all. If we spell it out more explicitly and rephrase it a bit, we'd probably arrive at something like

> For each situation, I have an unknown but non-zero number of duplicates.

or with almost the same meaning

> For every situation, I have an unknown but non-zero number of duplicates.

Thus, I think *por* combined with *ĉiu* could be used here:

> Por ĉiu situacio mi havas duplikatojn.

or to mirror the original word order more closely

> Mi havas duplikatojn por ĉiu situacio.

Answer (score 1):

Repetitition can be expressed with `po` with an indefinite quantity, if `po` is followed by `kelkaj` / `iuj`; English `some`. `Po` reading as *in every case*.

> There were some flowers on every table (on all tables) in the restaurant.
>
> *Estas po kelkaj floroj sur la tabloj en la restoracio.*

I hope your language sence for this strange preposition concurs.

For the other cases better refrain using `po` as it really does not matter.

> I have duplicates for each situation.
>
> *Mi tenas kopiojn por kovri ĉiun situacion.*

As you see it would make more sense to make the sentence *more* informative, rather
than applying a rare construct.

Unless you want to express multiplicity per case:

> *Mi havas po diversajn kopiojn por ĉiuj situacioj.*